# Magento 2.1.0.0 new order email template preview and save 404 not found issue

Tags: magento2, email, template, magento2.1.0

My website is at magento 2.1.0  version when i load new order **email template**, it shows below error:

> Error: The template did not load. Please review the log for details.

To correct the error I updated the line`"var order.getShippingDescription()":"Shipping Description"`, with a comma `","`at the end as suggested in some support pages to resolve the template load issue.

Now I can load new order email template but the measure problem is that when I click to preview or save template it goes a **404 page** and nothing happen.

Some support page are saying to Install Magento 2.1.0-rc3 using composer.

What is Magento 2.1.0-rc3 and where I can get it download and install or there is any other option to resolve this issue .

I want to keep the megento 2.1.0 version for my website.

Please reply with the correct solution .